# CODE HELP: passing a string to another method, case statement fails with analysis

Tags: android, methods, android-studio, switch-statement, case

Good day All

I am struggling with this problem, I am not sure if I'm missing something obvious but the case statement/sorting method fails to return the correct result.

In short, the program recieves an input from a EditText (edtInput) and assigns it to

```
string temp in isValidNumeericSequence(string temp) {...}
```

where it gets tested for 
1. if temp is empty
2. first character is a numeric value
3. the string contains anything except numbers and/or operators (operators specified in arrOperators)

The result from toast always refers to error_message 2, no matter what characters in the string, it always stays by error_message 2

IF I change the (temp == "" ) to (temp != ""), then it changes and sticks to error_message 1...

this might not be the most optimal method of calculating a equation, but its a simple start for me

p.s. If anything seems/looks abnormal, or irregular use of functions, please point them out, I would appreciate it...

I have tried debugging, but I seem to be missing something.

**java file:**

```
package com.cyberstudios.interpreter.interpreter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class MainForm extends Activity {

    private TextView lblAnswer, showText;
    private EditText edtInput;
    public Button btnShowHint, btnCalculate, btnClose;
    public String [] arrEditStore;
    public String arrOperators [] = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "(", ")"} ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_form);
        edtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtInput) ;
        lblAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblAnswer) ;
        btnShowHint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHelp);
        btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow) ;
    }

    public  void calculate(View vw)
    {
        String temp = edtInput.toString(), error_message = "";

        //--------------------------------------ERROR HANDLER----------------------------------------------------------
        switch (isValidNumericSequence(temp)) {
            case 0:
                sortInput(temp);
                break;

            case 1:
                error_message = "Dumb Shit, enter a sum, want me to read your mind?" ;
                break;

            case 2:
                error_message = "Think I'm an idiot, I need a number to start with, not a sign or a letter";
                break;

            case 3:
                error_message = "Moron!!! Are we doing word puzzles or character drawing, enter numbers and operators, not letters and punctuation, its not English class!" ;
                break;
        }
        makeText(this, error_message, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        arrEditStore = new String[edtInput.length()] ;

        lblAnswer.setText("No Answer");

//        applyBODMAS();
/*        double answer = CalcFromArray();
        lblAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(answer));*/
    }

   /* private double CalcFromArray() {
        return 0;
    }*/

    /*private void applyBODMAS()
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= arrEditStore.length; k++)
        {
            arrEditStore[k] = "0";
        }
    }*/

    private int isValidNumericSequence(String temp)//checks if string contains any digits
    {
    // Works with error codes, error code will be updated to be more user friendly
    // by reporting the position of errors:

    //  Code 0 : No error
    //  Code 1 : Empty String
    //  Code 2 : First character must be of numeric type
    //  Code 3 : There is an invalid character in the sequence

        makeText(this, "this is edtInput text - " + edtInput.toString(), LENGTH_SHORT).show(); ;
        makeText(this, "this is temp text - " + temp, LENGTH_SHORT).show(); ;
        if (temp == "") {
            return 1;
        }else {
            if (!Character.isDigit(temp.charAt(0)))
                return 2;
            for (int x = 1; x <= temp.length(); x++) {
                for (int k = 1; k <= arrOperators.length; k++) {
                    if (temp.charAt(x) != arrOperators.toString().charAt(k) || temp.charAt(x) >= 9 || temp.charAt(x) <= 0)
                        return 3;
                }
            }
        }

        return 0 ;
    }

    private void sortInput(String temp)
    {
        int x,y, count = 0;
        for (x=1; x<temp.length()+1; x=x+1)
        {
            for (y=0;y<= arrOperators.length;y=y+1)
            {
                if(temp.substring(x,x+1).equals(arrOperators[y]))
                {
                    arrEditStore[count++] = temp.substring(0, x-1);
                    arrEditStore[count++] = arrOperators[y] ;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void _showHint(View vw)
    {
        final Dialog showHintDialog = new Dialog(this);

        showHintDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        showHintDialog.setTitle("How to enter data");

        showHintDialog.show();
        btnClose = (Button) showHintDialog.findViewById(R.id.button) ;
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                showHintDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_form, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I dont believe the logcat or any xml files are nessassary, but if it needs be, I can post them

Thanx in advance

Comment: have you tried with .equals()???

Comment: edtInput.toString() is totally wrong!!!  you need to use edtInput.getText().toString() 

You are using edittext totally wrong...

Read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html

Comment: Indeed @oguzhand seems to have identified a primary issue, you are using what is basically a "handy name" of the editText object rather than the contents of its text field.

Comment: and @Chris Stratton for your answers, it solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you too @oguzhand and @Chris Stratton for the comments

> edtInput.toString() is totally wrong!!! you need to use
>   edtInput.getText().toString() You are using edittext totally wrong...
>   Read this:
>   developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html – 
>   oguzhand

and

> Indeed @oguzhand seems to have identified a primary issue, you are
>   using what is basically a "handy name" of the editText object rather
>   than the contents of its text field. –  Chris Stratton

I simply replaced any edtInput.toString() with edtInput.getText().toString() and it worked perfectly

Thank you